# How to filter a dictionary/ Object by keys in JavaScript using Html Input?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am new to programming. I will like to know if there's a way to filter a list of dictionaries by keys with a different value for each key in the object.

I want to Filter these countries by name.

Here is the link to my repl: https://repl.it/@husnainfareed/CountryList

```
const countries = {

'A' : {
    'Abu Dhabi (U.A.E)': 'https://asdf.com',
    'Abuja (Nigeria)' : 'https://asdf.com',
    'Addis Ababa (Ethiopia)' : '',
    'Amman (Jordan)' : '',
    'Ankara (Turkey)' : '',
    'Ashgabat(Turkmenistan)':'',
    'Nur-Sultan (Kazakhstan)':'',
    'Athens (Greece)':''

  },

'C' : {
    'Cairo (Egypt)' : 'https://asdf.com',
    'Chengdu (China)': '',
    'Chicago':'',
    'Canberra':'',
    'Colombo (Sri Lanka)':'',
    'Copenhagen (Denmark)':''
  }
}
```

```
Object.keys(countries).forEach(letter => {
  $('#table').append(`
  <div id="${letter}">
      <h1>${letter}</h1>
    </div>`);
  Object.keys(countries[letter]).forEach(cn => {

    const mainAlphabet = letter;
    const countryName = cn;
    const url = countries[letter][countryName];
    $('#' + letter).append(`<div class='list'>
    <a href="${url}">${countryName}</a>`).attr('target','_blank');

  });

 $('#table').append(`</div>`);

})
```

**Expected Output:**

Input:

HTML Search: Australia

Output:

Australia

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: Side note: That's not a *dictionary*, it's an *object*. Objects are not just dictionaries or hashmaps. If you want just a dictionary/hashmap, in modern environments you'd use `Map` instead of an object. (But you can use objects as though they were dictionaries if necessary. If you do, usually it's best to create them without any prototype: `Object.create(null)`.)

Comment: enter sample result

Comment: Just a heads up, in javascript, those are simply called objects, not dictionaries. You also don't need to use quotes for keys when initializing an object.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem.

You need to replace

```
Object.keys(countries[letter]).forEach(
// In this case you want to enumerate properties that can not be enumerated using forEach instead use `for in`
```

with

```
for (let cn in countries[letter])
```

Please see this article link:
https://alligator.io/js/for-of-for-in-loops/